# "Class 'App\Models\Schema' not found",

Tags: php, laravel

me esta arrojando este error

> "message": "Class 'App\Models\Schema' not found",
>
> "exception": "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError",
>
> "file": "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.3.12-0\apache2\htdocs\ct2\app\Models\CreaModel.php",
>
> "line": 16

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CreaModel extends Model
{
    function crearCampo($parametros){

      DB::beginTransaction();

      $data = array("nuevoCargo" => $parametros["nuevoCargo"],);

      $contacto = Schema::create('tbl_cargo_empleado', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string($data);
        });

      if($contacto){

        DB::commit();
        return array("response" => true, "message" => "Campo Creado con Éxito.");

      }else{

        DB::rollBack();
        return array("response" => false, "message" => "Error al tratar de crear el Campo.");

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y muestra toda la clase, el error aparentemente es el de no importar una clase.

Comment: puede que sea eso, no lo e colocado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para futuros visitantes que utilicen Laravel, la otra respuesta puede ser un poco confusa por dos motivos:

1. No se está intentando usar un «modelo», lo que se intenta utilizar es una clase, tal y como lo dice el mensaje de error.
2. La clase que se debe importar para poder ejecutar la transacción en la base de datos es `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema`, que de hecho es un Facade.

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   ```

Comment: Aparte de lo indicado, @Shaz, fijate que esta tambien tratando de crear ¿una nueva columna desde un modelo? pero lo que hace es crear una tabla en lugar de modificar la existente. Quizas deberia tambien usar `Schema::table` es decir `Schema::table('nombre_tabla', function($table) { $table->string('nombre_campo'); });` para añadir una nueva columna.